# isc-dhcp-server [ok] and running but doesn't seem to work at all

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, dhcp, wifi-hotspot, isc-dhcpd

I am attempting to create my own Wireless Access point with compatible hardware and software.

Running cmd **service isc-dhcp-server start** and **service hostapd start** on my **Raspbian** box returns

Running cmd **service hostapd start** returns

```
[ ok ] Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapd. 
[ ok ] Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpd.
```

Checking my **var/log/syslog** file shows no complaints

```
dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.2.2
dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
dhcpd: All rights reserved.
dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.2.2
dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
dhcpd: All rights reserved.
dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
dhcpd: Wrote 1 leases to leases file.
```

However when I try to connect to my Access Point which I can see is listed in the available networks, I am unable to connect.

What also seems to be important is that in my **var/log/syslog** file I do not see any activity regarding this connection. (in the past running dhcp the log file usually shows a lot of data when any client tries to connect etc)

---

**Update 08/09/15 15:43**

Some of my **/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf** file's important parts

```
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.42.10 192.168.42.50;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.42.255;
    option routers 192.168.42.1;
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    option domain-name "local";
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

my **/etc/network/interfaces** file

```
...
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

iface wlan1 inet static
        address 192.168.42.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0

up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
...
```

my **/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf** file

```
interface=wlan1
driver=rtl871xdrv
ssid=aaaaBBBB
hw_mode=g
channel=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=rrrrrrrr
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Running cmd **ifconfig -a** returns

```
wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:02:22:22:11:11
          inet addr:192.168.42.1  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

---

**Update 08/09/15 16:12**

My **/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server** file contains

```
...
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server initscript
...
INTERFACES="wlan1"
```

My **/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward** file contains

```
1
```

Pinging **192.168.42.1** through *SSH* (eth0 192.168.1.100) returns

```
**ping 192.168.42.1** returns 

PING 192.168.42.1 (192.168.42.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.42.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.372 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.42.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.273 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.42.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.271 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.42.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.270 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.42.1: icmp_req=5 ttl=64 time=0.266 ms
^X64 bytes from 192.168.42.1: icmp_req=6 ttl=64 time=0.268 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.42.1: icmp_req=7 ttl=64 time=0.266 ms
^C
--- 192.168.42.1 ping statistics ---
```

---

**Update 09/09/15 18:24**

Running the following cmd whilst trying to connect to the AP from another machine

```
tcpdump -i wlan1 -vv
```

returns

```
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

cmd

```
iwconfig
```

returns

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"aaaaBBBB"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Master  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:02:22:22:11:11
          Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

My **/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases** file contains

The format of this file is documented in the dhcpd.leases(5) manual page.

## This lease file was written by isc-dhcp-4.2.2

lease 192.168.42.10 {
  starts 4 2015/09/03 20:10:01;
  ends 4 2015/09/03 20:20:01;
  tstp 4 2015/09/03 20:20:01;
  cltt 4 2015/09/03 20:10:01;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:02:22:22:11:11;
}
server-duid "\000\001\000\000\031h\026\000\000\000\000\000\000\"";

---

### What I have tried to fix this

**hostapd**

- changing *drivers=* in **/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf** to **driver=nl80211** and **driver=rtl8192cu** - Both result in **service hostapd** failing to start

Comment: Can you ping the AP over wireless if you set a static IP? It's difficult to tell from your question if this is a connectivity issue or just that the `dhcpd` service isn't handing out addresses. Did you specify a range in the config file? Can you show this range to us? Using `tcpdump`, does the `dhcpd` server see the incoming packets? Is it attempting to return anything?

Comment: Check with a sniffer (tcpdump/wireshark) if there is dhcp traffic

Comment: @stevieb I have updated my post with alot more info

Comment: @arved when using tcpdump from my raspbian I can see all info seems to only contain addresses **192.168.1.3** which is my windows machine with **SSH** open to my linux box. I tried to connect to my newly created AP whilst tcpdump was running but I did not see any addresses **192.168.42.1** or of a similar range

Comment: i think you might be listening on the wrong interface, but i don't know your setup in detail. What you also might want to do, start dhcpd manual in debugging mode (-d commandline arg)

Comment: It might be firewall. IPv4 `bootpc` and `bootps` packets are weird. They are all udp and initial requests (non-renewal) have an initial source address of 0.0.0.0; so the only way you can tell source with `tcpdump` is by looking at the MAC.

Comment: @arved I have updated my post with what my **etc/default/isc-dhcp-server** file specificies which interfaces should be used. which is wlan1. Is this the file you would declare where and which interface to listen to on?

Comment: @stevieb I have updated my original post with alot more info, I believe it is DHCP not handing out an IP address. I have provided a range in my config file, and tcpdump doesnt seem to be collecting anything at all...

Comment: I am willing to pay for help to resolve this, I can pay BTC in advance if anybody would like to go further, I have spent over 10 hours on this now and I am ripping my hair out, I do not know what else to try, the services seem to run fine without reporting any errror...

Comment: facing the same problem, have you got any solutions to this one? would appreciate kind revert.